VSCode does not recognice RCLCPP_INFO
For days, I've been struggling with my VSCode setup.
By no reason, VSCode started highlighting all RCLCPP_INFO, RCLCPP_WARN, RCLCPP_ERROR, ... function calls.
The error message is as follows:

I installed the following VSCode extensions:

C/C++
C/C++ Extension Pack
C/C++ Themes
CMake
CMakeTools
ROS

Updating the C++ Properties according to:

provides me an auto-generated c_cpp_properties.json:

I tried out the following:

Re-installing VSCode
Re-installing all extensions
Re-installing ROS 2
Re-installing Ubuntu
Using a c_cpp_properties.json according to:  Visual Studio Code IncludePath Issue with ROS headers
Playing around with settings.json

Hope that anyone can find out what else I can do.
Thanks in advance!

I could achieve a stable IntelliSense experience with ROS2 by generating the compile commands:
colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON

In this case, colcon generates a combined compile_commands.json in the build folder, so that the following c_cpp_properties.json file does the trick:
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "ROS",
      "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json",
      "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
      "cStandard": "gnu11",
      "cppStandard": "c++14"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}

So far, the ROS extension hasn't overwritten the file, so that the IntelliSense experience is stable. Additionally, it looks like this combined file is also considered by clang-tidy.

Can you delete the .vscode folders in your workspace and then reload the window with:
CTRL+SHIFT+P and select reload window?

Yes. Then the c_cpp_properties.json is re-generated as before and the issue remains.

Can you add your header files as an edit?
